# properties include properties Struts2

Tags: java, properties, struts2

I have a project in Struts2 and have difficulty making a includes the properties.
I explain the problem better

I have a number of properties in my project with the label that are at the level WEB-INF  classes

```
Cliente1_Mybundel.properties
```

In relation to the customer with the IF in java I load

```
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle ("Cliente1_Mybundel.properties");
```

and everything works.

My problem is to include a properties within another `Generico_Mybundel.properties` properties because they use it all customers
Specifically I would like to do that within the file includes `Cliente1_Mybundel.properties` of `Generico_Mybundel.properties`

Example:

Content of `Cliente1_Mybundel.properties`:

```
inserimento=inserimento dato

modifica=modifica dato

<% Include file = "WEB-INF / classes / Generico_Mybundel.properties"%>

Cliente1_Mybundel.properties -> (INCLUDE) -> Generico_Mybundel.properties
```

Can it be done?
I tried various include but are not able to make it work

Comment: Have you looked at the way Struts2 loads the properties files (i.e. the code)?  My guess is that it just uses the standard Java properties API and this doesn't support includes.

Comment: Why not to include your `Generico_Mybundel.properties` in struts.xml or using `LocalizedTextUtil`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
The Problem struts that do not allow me to use two files simultaneously.
Reads the label in a file or another in relation to the language but I want to load two files together

struts.properties

struts.custom.i18n.resources = Cliente1_Mybundel.properties; Generico_Mybundel;

you can do
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle ("Cliente1_Mybundel.properties", "Generico_Mybundel.properties");

I do not need to use one or the other file in relation to language but use the 2 files together

Thanks

Comment: You can define multiple files in `struts.custom.i18n.resources`.